# Is there a more efficient way to sort an Array in an Array in an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, controls

For the following **array-object-thing** structure:

```
Events : {
    events : [
        {
          startDTG : {day: 0, month: 0, year: 0, time: "" },
          endDTG : {day: 0, month: 0, year: 0, time: "" },
          mode: ""
        },
        ...
    ],
    blah...,
    blah...,
    blah...
}
```

I am struggling to find a more efficient way to sort the `events` objects based on the `startDTG` key (Date-Time Group). Currently I use the following, but I feel there has to be a better way to do it!

```
SortEvents: function() {
    this.Events.events.sort(function(a, b){return a.startDTG.time - b.startDTG.time});
    this.Events.events.sort(function(a, b){return a.startDTG.day - b.startDTG.day});
    this.Events.events.sort(function(a, b){return a.startDTG.month - b.startDTG.month});
    this.Events.events.sort(function(a, b){return a.startDTG.year - b.startDTG.year});
},
```

**Edit 1**: The desire is to be sorted by `Year > Month > Day > Time`

I am at a critical point in which I am to abandon this custom DTG in the name of efficiency it is needed. I can post the entire code if requested, but might not make total sense as it is JS written to work within a Proprietary Control system called "Medialon"

**Edit 2**:  Added a quick-made `JSON` code dump below to assist with readability of structure. Ignore the fact they are all "strings" it is how Medialon stringifies for persistence

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "startDTG": {
        "day": "8",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "06:35",
        "dayName": "5"
      },
      "endDTG": {
        "day": "9",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "08:35",
        "dayName": "6"
      },
      "mode": "1"
    },
    {
      "startDTG": {
        "day": "27",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "17:35",
        "dayName": "3"
      },
      "endDTG": {
        "day": "28",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "06:35",
        "dayName": "4"
      },
      "mode": "1"
    },
    {
      "startDTG": {
        "day": "1",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "14:35",
        "dayName": "5"
      },
      "endDTG": {
        "day": "2",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2019",
        "time": "12:35",
        "dayName": "6"
      },
      "mode": "1"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: In the above, all your going to end up with is the events sorted by `year`,.  So a more efficient way, is to not do the other sorts.. :)  I'm assuming your wanting to sort by `year` then `month`, then `day` then `time`, but that's not how you do a compound sort.

Comment: Can you clean up the code sample a bit? It's hard to tell what's an array and what's an object. I think you are missing a few `{}`...

Comment: You can separate the sorting criteria with `||` i.e. `this.Events.events.sort(function(a, b){return a.startDTG.year- b.startDTG.year ||  a.startDTG.month- b.startDTG.month || ... //etc})`

Comment: @Keith: because pretty much all sort implementations are now stable, this will do what's desired: sort by year first, then month, then day.  (Time as a string is more problematic).  This is definitely not the most efficient, though.

Comment: Are you trying to sort on StartDTG or EndDTG? Your inner events object is not well-formated, an array can't have keys

Comment: What’s `time`? Your example shows an empty string so it’s hard to say, but if the real ones are strings like `"12:34"`, subtraction isn’t going to work very well.

Comment: Time string is in 24 hr notation of HH:MM so thoughts are that 01:30 should always sort lower than 18:35  ect   (still testing)

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Edge doesn't have stable sort if that's an issue, and neither did Chrome until recently.  And ES7 doesn't state a stable sort is a requirement, so I'd be very careful relying on such behaviour.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value/4760279#4760279

Comment: Why are you storing your times this way in the first place, instead of just using a single property with a `Date` object?

Comment: @Barmar At first I went down that route, but the Medialon program itself uses it's own odd date system which whenever you interface it is JS it comes in as 2 strings.  One being a DD/MM/YYYY string the other being a HH:MM:SS/ms string.  Being a scheduling system, I felt it less intensive to match their formatting to concat, compare and check for events rather than doing a lot of conversions..  Though this problem comes as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure of your data structure, but something like this should be close:

```js
const events = [
  {name: 'a', startDTG: {year: 2019, month: 1,  day: 4,  time: '14:21:46'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'b', startDTG: {year: 2018, month: 10, day: 7,  time: '12:13:59'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'c', startDTG: {year: 2019, month: 1,  day: 4,  time: '09:23:51'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'd', startDTG: {year: 2019, month: 1,  day: 2,  time: '15:02:36'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'e', startDTG: {year: 2017, month: 9,  day: 17, time: '03:25:29'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'f', startDTG: {year: 2017, month: 9,  day: 17, time: '03:25:28'}, endDTG: ''},
  {name: 'g', startDTG: {year: 2018, month: 4,  day: 14, time: '11:07:42'}, endDTG: ''},
]

events.sort((
  {startDTG: {year: y1, month: m1, day: d1, time: t1}}, 
  {startDTG: {year: y2, month: m2, day: d2, time: t2}}
) => 
  // y1 - y2 || m1 - m2 || d1 - d2 || (t1 < t2 ? -1 : t1 > t2 ? 1 : 0)           
  y1 - y2 || m1 - m2 || d1 - d2 || t1.localeCompare(t2)
)

console.log(events)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's much better. I wonder if `localeCompare` might be easier to read than the ternary for the times.

Comment: @MarkMeyer: yes, that definitely looks better.

Comment: @MarkMeyer  The OP mentioned efficient, so is maybe looking for the fastest.   A tenery should be quicker, and a quick benchmark make localeCompare about 70% slower.

Comment: Well, they're both there for the OP to choose from. Either way, this should likely be quite a bit faster than performing four separate sorts.

Comment: @ScottSauyet So there is a little bit of fenangling I have to do to get JS to work in this program. For the alias portion you did right after the .sort(), what is the technical name for it so I can read up on it a bit more.   It doesn't work as a drop in snippit though it looks promising!

Comment: I have no idea what "a drop in snippit" means, but parameter desctucturing is described in [an MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).  (The entire article is worth a read.) . It's pretty much equivalent to `...sort((a, b) => { const y1 = a.startDTG.year, m1 = a.startDTG.month, ... y2 = b.startDTG.year, ... t2 = b.startDTG.time; return y1 - y2 || ...}`. See also [Axel Rauschmayer's article](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be mapping your data to a [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then comparing the milliseconds returned with [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

```js
let data = {
  "events": [
    {
      "startDTG": {"day": "8", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "5"},
      "endDTG": {"day": "9", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "6"},
      "mode": "1"
    },
    {
      "startDTG": {"day": "27", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "3"},
      "endDTG": {"day": "28", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "4"},
      "mode": "1"
    },
    {
      "startDTG": {"day": "1", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "5"},
      "endDTG": {"day": "2", "month": "2", "year": "2019", "time": "6:35", "dayName": "6"},
      "mode": "1"
    }
  ]
};

const startDTGToStr = o => `${o.year}-${o.month}-${o.day} ${o.time}`

data.events.sort((a, b) =>
{
    a = new Date(startDTGToStr(a.startDTG));
    b = new Date(startDTGToStr(b.startDTG));
    return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
});

console.log(data.events);
```

Comment: Although this is going to be faster than sorting an array 4 times, there is a bit of overhead in creating a Date object for every compare.  And as such is slower than doing a compound compare like @Scott shows below.  But if the OP had stored a DateTime in the first place, this would be the way to go.